# UILabel text doesn't feel like being set

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code

```
NSLog(@"%@", bottomTitle);
[self.bottomTitleLabel setText:bottomTitle];
NSLog(@"%@", self.bottomTitleLabel.text);
```

Here is the output

```
2013-07-29 14:37:30.977 Minoe[20853:c07] Choose a category
2013-07-29 14:37:30.978 Minoe[20853:c07] (null)
```

Here is my Outlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bottomTitleLabel;
```

I don't understand why my text isn't being set.

EDIT: Label was null, why?

EDIT 2: The view wasn't loaded at the point in time the text was being set.

Comment: You didn't hook up the outlet.

Comment: It is hooked up @Kevin

Comment: Double check that `bottomTitleLabel` is properly wired up in your storyboard/xib. Could also try setting a breakpoint and seeing if self.bottomTitleLabel is non-nil, or add another log statement: `NSLog(@"%@", self.bottomTitleLabel)`.

Comment: NSLog `self.bottomTitleLabel` itself (not the .text).  Here's betting it'll be null.

Comment: Maybe it's just being moody :)

Comment: Try hooking it up again

Comment: I removed the connection and then relinked the Label still nothing

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong xib file.  Do you maybe have several by similar names?

Comment: +1 for figuring that out on your own.  We'd have taken another hour or so to think of that possible cause.

Comment: This is one of the cases when `NilPointerException` would be helpful in Obj-C :)